# GWTMockito: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when writing tests. Why?

Tags: java, gwt, testing, junit, mockito

I’m attempting to write my first test for my GWT site but when I run my tests from the command line (I am developing with Eclipse though) I get the following error:

```
[junit] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Composite

[junit]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
[junit]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:792)
[junit]     at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
[junit]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
[junit]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
[junit]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
[junit]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
[junit]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[junit]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
[junit]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
[junit]     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
[junit]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
[junit]     at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
[junit]     at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2387)
[junit]     at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1796)
[junit]     at com.google.gwtmockito.GwtMockitoTestRunner.<init>(GwtMockitoTestRunner.java:106)
[junit]     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
[junit]     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)

[junit] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Composite

[junit]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
[junit]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
[junit]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[junit]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
[junit]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
[junit]     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
[junit]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

I have included gwt-user.jar in my webapp/WEB-INF/lib folder too.

Anyone have any idea what is wrong??

Comment: What does your classpath look like when running from command line? Does it include all jars from your `webapp/WEB-INF/lib` directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my test compile classpath wasn't even set!